# How to find solution to a non-homogenous system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

> Let $X'=AX + b(t)$ be a system of differential equations  where: $X(t) = (x_1(t),...,x_n(t))$, $A\in\mathcal M_n({\mathbb{R}})$ and $b(t) = (b_1(t),..,b_n(t))$.

How do I solve this system using the variations of constants method?

I know that if $M(t)=(x_1(t)|....|x_n(t))$ a matrix of fundamental solutions and

$$X(t)=c_1(t)x_1(t)+...+c_n(t)x_n(t)=M(t)C(t)$$

where $C(t) = (c_1(t)|..|c_n(t))$

And that $C(t)$ verifies $C'(t)=M^{-1}(t)b(t)$

If I have an example like:

$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}x'=x+y-\cos t\\y'=-2x-y+\sin t+\cos t\end{array}\right.$$

How do I actually solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost done, as you can simply integrate the function $M^{-1}(t)b(t)$ over $t$ to obtain the function $C(t)$, up to constants of integration.

You write your example in the form
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\dot{x}} = \left( \begin{array}{c}
\dot{x}\\
\dot{y}
\end{array}
\right) = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1\\
-2 & -1
\end{array}
\right) \left( \begin{array}{c}
x\\
y
\end{array}
\right) + \left( \begin{array}{c}
-\cos(t)\\
\sin(t)+\cos(t)
\end{array}
\right) = \boldsymbol{\underline{A}} \boldsymbol{x} + \boldsymbol{b}(t),
\end{equation}
which has the general solution
\begin{equation}
  \boldsymbol{x}(t) = \boldsymbol{\underline{M}}(t) \int \boldsymbol{\underline{M}}^{-1}(t) \boldsymbol{b}(t) \, \mathrm{d}t,
\end{equation}
where $\boldsymbol{\underline{M}}(t) := e^{t \boldsymbol{\underline{A}}}$ is a matrix exponential (with inverse $\boldsymbol{\underline{M}}^{-1}(t) = e^{-t \boldsymbol{\underline{A}}}$). The constants of integration are contained in the indefinite integral. We obtain
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\underline{M}}(t) = e^{t\boldsymbol{\underline{A}}} = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
  \cos(t) + \sin(t) & \sin(t)\\
  -2\sin(t) & \cos(t) - \sin(t)
  \end{array}
\right), \quad \int \boldsymbol{\underline{M}}^{-1}(t) \boldsymbol{b}(t) \, \mathrm{d}t = \left( \begin{array}{c}
C_1 - t\\
C_2 + t
\end{array}
\right),
\end{equation}
$C_1, C_2 \in \mathbb{R}$, and finally
\begin{equation}
  \boldsymbol{x}(t) = \left( \begin{array}{c}
x(t)\\
y(t)
\end{array}
\right) = \left( \begin{array}{c}
  -t \cos(t) + C_1 (\cos(t) + \sin(t)) + C_2 \sin(t)\\
  t \cos(t) + t \sin(t) - 2 C_1 \sin(t) + C_2 (\cos(t)-\sin(t))
  \end{array}
\right).
\end{equation}